# How to open new tab in an existing incognito window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, incognito-mode

I'm writing a chrome extension about creating new tab from context menus in an incognito window. I'm using a script like this:

```
chrome.windows.create({url: "https://google.com", incognito: true});
```

The script works, but it always pops out a new window when it activates. Is there any way to open a new tab in an existing incognito window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a tab inside an existing window you can use [`chrome.tabs.create()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) specifying the `windowId` of an existing window. To know which one of the open windows is in incognito mode, you can use [`chrome.windows.getAll()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-getAll) to get an array of currently open windows and iterate through the results until you see one with `incognito` set to `true`.

Here's a working example:

```
chrome.windows.getAll({populate: false, windowTypes: ['normal']}, function(windows) {
    for (let w of windows) {
        if (w.incognito) {
            // Use this window.
            chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://google.com", windowId: w.id});
            return;
        }
    }

    // No incognito window found, open a new one.
    chrome.windows.create({url: "https://google.com", incognito: true});
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful. And also reminding the incognito need to set as "spanning" at manifest.

Comment: This is what I was hoped for to work, but seems that in my Chrome 89.0 the incognito windows are not returned by getAll. Why could this be?

Comment: @ZorgoZ you need to allow your extension to run in incognito mode.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, thanks, I have come to this conclusion too...