# How to create incognito tab from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to open an url in incognito mode from chrome extension. Opening it in a new incognito window is simple, but there is no such property for [creating new tab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-create).

I tried to store the window object created but seems that the callback parameter is always null incognito windows, but properly populated for normal windows.

Is there a way to open url in incognito tab if there already is an incognito window?

The solution here ([How to open new tab in an existing incognito window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60328589/how-to-open-new-tab-in-an-existing-incognito-window)) looks fine, but it does not work for me. No incognito window is returned by `getAll()`. Does this need any special permission in the manifest (aside `tabs`) to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228118/how-to-open-new-incognito-window-with-javascript-google-chrome

Comment: @MsonC no duplicate, I need tab, not window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that I need to explicitly enable *incognito* access to the extension to get intel about incognito windows, even created by my extension itself.